# Android Ionic App not navigating properly in phone

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have an android app built via Ionic Framework. The issue is it is working fine in the browser but not working as expected in the android app, which I installed on my phone. The issue is that I am not able to navigate the app on my phone.After connecting to chrome dev tools, seeing the link in the dev tools I found out that there is a difference. The link in dev tools is

```
file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/sideMenu/dashboard/dashboard/month
```

and link in my browser is

```
http://localhost:8100/#/sideMenu/dashboard/dashboard/month
```

could this be the reason? Most of you would be doing the same thing. So how do you guys resolve it?

**EDIT** 
Screen shot of chrome inspect[image]

Comment: Can you see anything on your mobile? Or is there a white screen?

Comment: No "the white screen of death" isn't there. I checked the chrome://inspect and found these errors. (Check edit.) could they be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were errors in my app generating from the fact that It was not able to access the internet. Download the Cordova's whitelisting plugin. It should do the trick and it's a known issue that if you have even a single error in your app. It could possibly break the flow.